# extjs4 - simplest way to enable/disable tabs in tabpanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there a simple way to enable/disable tabs in a tabpanel at runtime?

At the moment, I do:

```js
Ext.getCmp('thetabpanel).getTabBar().items.get(1).setDisabled(true);
```

That seems really complicated, but I can't seem to find any obvious method at the tab panel level to do that directly.

Thanks

Comment: I think that your approach is the only way to do this.

Comment: @Molecule. Thanks for your input.. Maybe put that as an answer if you're positive there's no other way.

Comment: I'd rather not. I'm not completely sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method down to get the tab,

```
Ext.getCmp('thetabppanel').down('#itemIdForTheTab').setDisabled(true);
```

check the documentation for down http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/docs/#/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-down

Comment: Thanks. That looks a bit simpler. I'm still suprised there isn't a simple tab accessor by index at the panel level..

Answer (score 2):

You can access the items property (witch is a MixedCollection) and use the `getAt()` method:

```
Ext.getCmp('thetabpanel').items.getAt(1).setDisabled(true);
```

See documentation [link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection-method-getAt)

edit:typos

Comment: Yes, get/getAt, that's what I was using. Good to know I don't have to go through getTabBar() first (oddly I thought I had tried your version but couldn't make it work, seems ok now though). Thanks

Comment: Still amazed that at version 4, ext doesn't have an enableTab method at the tabpanel level..

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the new query features:

```js
var panel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('thetabpanel panel[id="#itemIdForTheTab"]')[0];
panel.setDisabled(true);
```

See the [Ext API on ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query) for more details.